# Is there a graph that shows the thrust required for a given airspeed?

Tags: aircraft-performance, cessna-172, cessna-150

I would like to see the graphical relationship between thrust required and airspeed for a typical general aviation aircraft, e.g. C-150 or C172 series.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49946/62), does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal flight, thrust required is the same as drag.  Go to the specific graph referenced in this answer [How close is the air resistance or drag force to be proportional to the speed squared?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74801/how-close-is-the-air-resistance-or-drag-force-to-be-proportional-to-the-speed-sq/74917#74917), and you'll have your answer, or close to it.

The specific graph referenced here is for "a conceptual two-seat light sport aircraft (LSA) designed to cruise between 80 and 100 kts".  A Cessna 150 or 172 might need somewhat more power for the same cruise speed.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a graph, much like a glider polar.

Comment: That's what the figure I'm referencing is-- check it out.

Comment: I'm sure someone will eventually provide a link to a similar graph for a more typical GA plane but it's a start--

Comment: I couldn't locate a graph.  Lots of good info though.  Running out of time now, but will check in later.

Comment: The graph is near the bottom of the linked webpage-- it's the third-to-last figure.

Comment: Thanks for the dialog. I found the following graph independently.  It shows the general functionality - and that is all I was looking for at this point.

Comment: It appears impossible to post a graphic, but here is the link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.studyflight.com%2Fflight-for-range-and endurance%2F&psig=AOvVaw273h0qbOE4yGtfoVZehxWn&ust=1582916444923000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjTpLW18ucCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD/

Comment: @MarkW -- your link seems a little confused, it seems something didn't get copied right-- if you scroll to third-to-last-figure on webpage linked in my post, you'll see what I'm talking about, probably very similar to the figure you were trying to link to.

Comment: you are correct.  The figures are similar, as one would expect. I simply "googled" Cessna 172 drag polar.  Here is (hopefully) a useable link. https://www.studyflight.com/flight-for-range-and-endurance/

Comment: In the first set of figures, I was looking for the graph on the left.  The "total drag" vs. Air speed that was in your reference is just beside it.  Thanks again...this was a fun dialog.